# Script to move files created before a certain date to another network location

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, file-transfer

Ok, this is a simple question I am sure but I'm a novice when it comes to batch scripting and programming so I hope I can find the answers I seek here.

## Machine Specifications

OS - Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard Edition Service Pack 2

RAM - 4GB

CPU - Dual Core Xeon 2.67GHz

## The situation

I have a server with a hard drive that I use for storing phone call recordings, it only has 350GB of space and is completely full so my recordings are no longer being stored until I clear it. These recordings have been piling up since 2011, so manually copying the files is nearly impossible since I don't have that much RAM and windows always times out and goes to not responding when I try.

## What I need to do

I need a script that will take the files from before a certain date (IE. before 1/1/2013) and move them to a share on my NAS unit at \192.168.x.x\Recordings and once they are finished being copied to that share to delete the original files from the hard drive to free up that space.

I'm sure this is easy and probably a stupid question to ask here but I really need to get this done as it is crucial for our customers/employees.

Thank you in advance for helpful answers!!! Very much appreciated!

Comment: We're not here to write scripts for you, just help when you get stuck or have specific questions. :)  So, what have you got already? Where are you getting stuck? Have you gone over questions like [Batch file to copy files from desktop location to another location?](http://superuser.com/questions/538051/batch-file-to-copy-files-from-desktop-location-to-another-location) yet?

Comment: Well, I know how to do xcopy to copy files but what I don't know how to do is make it search the directory for files created before a specific date, if I knew how to do that then I'm sure it would be easy to put the pieces together. The other thing I don't know how to do is delete those files with the script after they have been copied over. I am Googling to find out how to do this also so I might not need the answer shortly :)

Comment: So I basically need something to copy all files before a date. I know I can do 'xcopy from_location to_location /d:date' to copy the files created after a specific date, but what is the syntax for before a certain date?

Comment: copy time & date dependent files with `robocopy` & `forfiles`. Delete them with `forfiles` too :)

Comment: Look into using [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) or get away from batches completely and use [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powershell).  For example: Robocopy has a "MinAge" switch to skip files newer than a certain date.

Comment: Ok so can I use PowerShell on server 2003? I thought it was only 2008 and beyond.

Comment: `robocopy` works on all NT Windows, eg. XP, Server 2003 ...

Comment: Dan, instead of updating your question you should answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: Robocopy doesn't require Powershell to function.

Comment: I know that KronoS, but it was too early to answer, I had to wait 6 hours.

Answer (score 0):

If you [download and install the Windows 2000 Resource Kit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927229), it includes a command line utility called `robocopy` that can perform this task with one command.

Below is an example of how you would use `robocopy` for this:

`robocopy.exe C:\from_location C:\to_locations *.* /MAXAGE:MaximumAgeOfFilesToCopy /MINAGE:MinimumAgeOfFilesToCopy`

The below is from Robocopy's help (`robocopy /?`) that explains how the `/MAXAGE` and `/MINAGE` options work:

```
      /MAXAGE:n :: MAXimum file AGE - exclude files older than n days/date.
      /MINAGE:n :: MINimum file AGE - exclude files newer than n days/date.
      /MAXLAD:n :: MAXimum Last Access Date - exclude files unused since n.
      /MINLAD:n :: MINimum Last Access Date - exclude files used since n.
                   (If n < 1900 then n = n days, else n = YYYYMMDD date).
```